# Execute an instruction after finishing another in Javascript

Tags: javascript, iteration, order-of-execution

I'm having problems with the Javascript execution method. I have this piece of code:

```
let array = [];

list.forEach((item_1) => {
  let variable = 0;
  fetch("data.json")
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then((data) => {
      data.forEach((item_2) => {
        item_2.forEach((item_3) => {
          item_3forEach((item_4) => {
            if (condition) {
              variable += 1;
            }
          });
        });
      });
    });
  array.push({a:variable, b: item_1});
});
```

I need the variable to be append only when the iterations have finished, however when I run the project, the variable append first (with initial value 0) and then do the iterations.
How could I make it append only when the process is finished?

EDIT:
Due I wasn't very clear before, I share the piece of code that I ask the question about

```
for (let c = -100; c < 501; c += 100) {
  fetch(`data/votes_${c + 101}-${c + 200}.json`)
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then((data_vot) => {
      proy_etiq.forEach((eti_selec) => {
        let cont_si_tot = 0;
        data_vot.congresista.forEach((congresista) => {
          congresista.proyecto.forEach((proyecto) => {
            let cont_si = 0;
            eti_selec.proyectos.forEach((proy_selec) => {
              if (proyecto.id === proy_selec.id) {
                cont_si += proyecto.voto.si;
                proy_selec.votos[0] += cont_si;
              }
            });
            cont_si_tot += cont_si;
          });
        });
        flor_si.push({ Tema: eti_selec.nombre, abs: cont_si_tot });
      });
    });
}
```

The `proy_etiq` is a list that I alredy have,

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the append to happen as part of the iteration, then move it out of the iteration.

```js
let array = [];
let variable = 0;

list.forEach((item_1) => {
  ...
});

array.push(variable);
```

Comment: `fetch()` is asynchronous. How will this help?

Comment: @charlietfl It depends on the purpose of `fetch` and what OP ultimately wants out of their code. Personally, I don't see why OP is calling `fetch("data.json")` on _every_ iteration since it will presumably load the same thing every time, so it would be most prudent to pull that out of the loop as well and just load it once. However, OP's needs were not very clear from the question text, so I answered the question at face value.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what the exact purpose of the code is and I am sure you can definitely optimize it. That said, given your original code, I feel you can get it to work by consigning the array push process in another then block which will make sure it gets executed after the multiple loops have finished completing. Putting in the changed snippet below.

```js
let array = [];

list.forEach((item_1) => {
  let variable = 0;
  fetch("data.json")
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then((data) => {
      data.forEach((item_2) => {
        item_2.forEach((item_3) => {
          item_3forEach((item_4) => {
            if (condition) {
              variable += 1;
            }
          });
        });
        return 1;
      })
     //Changed code here.
    .then(_=>array.push({a: variable, b: item_1}))
    });
});
```